# How to protect a http post from Angular 2 to Express Server

Tags: javascript, security, express, angular, csrf

How do I protect a post call from a angular2 application to a Express server?

In my angular2 application I have a the following HTTP Post.

```
 const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    const data = {
      email: this.form.value.email
    };

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/user/email', data, {
      headers: headers
    })
```

Now I want to make sure that only my angular 2 application can make the post call to the user api. I did some research about csrf in combination with Express and Angular 2. In my Angular 2 application I made the following implementation to the app.module.ts file.

```
import { HttpModule, XSRFStrategy, CookieXSRFStrategy } from '@angular/http';

providers: [  {
            provide: XSRFStrategy,
            useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('csrftoken', 'X-CSRFToken')
        } ]
```

I think this is the right way to implement a XSRFStrategy to Angular 2?

For the implementation in Express I followed a few tutorials, but without any success. Most of the time I received:

```
ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
```

How do I implement the CSRF part in my Express api. Here is my Express config:

```
// call the packages we need
var express = require('express'); // call express
var app = express(); // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var csrf = require('csurf');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Something is happening.');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  next();
});

app.use('/api', router);

router.post('/user/email', function (req, res) {
 ..... [how to make sure that this post can only be fired from my angular 2 application ]
}
```

### Update #1

Did some more research and found the following in the Angular 2 docs:

```
//By default, Angular will look for a cookie called `'XSRF-TOKEN'`, and set
//* an HTTP request header called `'X-XSRF-TOKEN'` with the value of the cookie on each request,
```

So in my Express application I added the following parts:

```
const cookieOptions = {
  key: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
  secure: false,
  httpOnly: false,
  maxAge: 3600000
}

var csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: cookieOptions
})
```

and in the post route I implemented the protection as follow:

```
    router.post('/user/email', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
      console.log('post incomming');
}):
```

I got the following response headers back

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1167
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 21 Nov 2016 20:07:12 GMT
set-cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=O4JKkjAZRik2H7ml0DoxDc8s; Max-Age=3600000; Path=/
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:Express
```

And the request headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:38
content-type:application/json
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/profile/users
```

Comment: are you able to find a cookie with a name similar to csrf in the browser from express server side?

Comment: Hi Zubair. I updated my question with the responses I'm getting back.

Answer (score 2):

**How to implement CSRF protection with Angular2 and Express**

By default, Angular will look for a cookie called `'XSRF-TOKEN'`, and set
an HTTP request header called `'X-XSRF-TOKEN'` with the value of the cookie on each request.

To make sure that our backend can set a XSRF-TOKEN cookie, we have to proxy our calls to the api running on port 8080. We can do that with a proxy.config.json file.

```
{ 
  "/api/*" : {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug" 
  }
}
```

And in our package.json file we modify the scripts/start function to use our proxy.config.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
}
```

Now every time we run npm start our calls to /api are proxied to localhost:8080. Now we are ready to make a post call to our api server.

In our component we make a http post call and we set the headers to use content-type application/json.

```
ourfunction() {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  data = { key:value }

  this.http.post('/api/user/email', data, {
      headers: headers
  }).subscribe( (resp: any) => console.log('resp', resp));

}
```

That is everything we need to do at the Angular2 side. Now we are implement the Express side.

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var csrf = require('csurf');
var cors = require('cors')
```

We initialise our app and defining some middleware to use in our application.

```
const cookieOptions = {
  key: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
  secure: false,
  httpOnly: false,
  maxAge: 3600
}

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204 
};
```

Here we are setting the options to use for csrf and cors middleware.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port
const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: cookieOptions })
const router = express.Router();
```

Implementing the middelware. The order is very important to get the correct results.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', router);
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrfProtection);

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  next();
});
```

Thats all we need to do on the Express side. Now we can secure our post calls with a CSRF token.

Compleet express server file

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var csrf = require('csurf');
var cors = require('cors')

const cookieOptions = {
  key: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
  secure: false,
  httpOnly: false,
  maxAge: 3600
}

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204 
};

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port
const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: cookieOptions })
const router = express.Router();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', router);
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrfProtection);

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  next();
});

router.post('/user/email', function (req, res) {
  console.log('post incomming');
  console.log('req', req.body);
  res.send('testing..');
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```